# What competitions would be best to feature in an interstellar game show?

Tags: interspecies-relations

I am your host, Vos Sychem, and welcome to the Universes favorite game show, ***Cosmic KABOOM!!!*** Here, different pre-type 1 civilizations get to show of their skills for use higher forms of life. Today's roster includes

- The Vosians
- The Qualians
- The Telenoids

And

- The Humans

Remember, all these species must try to win, because, all three losers planets get eliminated, until a winner is found. Each team has 4 contestants, and unluckily for the humans, all their contestants are teenagers (laugh track). But, we must make sure the contest evaluates every important skill a species could have. What contest would be best for doing that?

Comment: Hunting, killing, cooking, and eating the competitors. Bonus points for savory cuts of meat and symmetrical presentation.

Comment: Clarifying what you mean by teenager could be helpful as alien species would likely have different aging rates than humans, let alone different methods of measuring time, making "teens" a non constant value between groups. Species may even go through multiple life stages with varying capability, so a "post-youth/nymph stage" or similar descriptor may not be possible without further knowledge of the species involved

Comment: @Zer0ah: humans ages 16-17

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, V. Sychem! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) (both of which require 5 rep to post on) useful. Have fun!

Comment: What's a type-1 civilisation or better yet, a pre type-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Kobayashi Maru.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru

> The Kobayashi Maru is a training exercise in the fictional Star Trek
>   universe designed to test the character of Starfleet Academy cadets in
>   a no-win scenario. The Kobayashi Maru test was first depicted in the
>   opening scene of the film Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan and also
>   appears in the 2009 film Star Trek. Screenwriter Jack B. Sowards is
>   credited with inventing the test. The test's name is occasionally used
>   among Star Trek fans or those familiar with the series to describe a
>   no-win scenario, a test of one's character or a solution that involves
>   redefining the problem.

I love the idea of this simulation.  The way to win: think bigger than the simulation (i.e. cheat).  The simulation has rules but the larger world has only the rules of physics.

So too your contestants.  The pointless contests that are part of the game show disguise the real test of a higher form of life: the ability of the contestants to redefine a contest which, as posed, has unacceptable outcomes.  Creativity, calculated violence, cooperation (even between rivals), perceptiveness and intuition all come into play.  This also is, as I udnerstand it, the theme underlying the Hunger Games series.